# How can I launch a C application from terminal, and pass in paramaters to int main(int argc, char *argv[])?

Tags: c++, macos, xcode

I'm new to development on Mac - I'm coding in xcode and I can't figure out how to launch my application with paramaters. I can navigate to the application directory and do something along the lines of:

```
open application
```

But I can't do:

```
open application param1 param2
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you coding in C or C++? Your title says C, but your tag says C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `--args` flag, available in OS X 10.6.2 or later:

```
open application --args param1 param2
```

See [How can I run an application with command line arguments in Mac OS](https://superuser.com/questions/16750/how-can-i-run-an-application-with-command-line-arguments-in-mac-os) for more information.